# Is there any difference in meaning hetween "talk with each other" and "talk together"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Is there any difference in meaning hetween *talk with each other* and *talk together*? For example:

> My family and I stayed in last night, so we had plenty of time to **talk with each other**.
>
> My family and I stayed in last night, so we had plenty of time to **talk together**.

If there is no difference, then which one is more common? Would it be even more natural to just omit *with each other* and *together* altogether?

Comment: More common is the simpler "we had plenty of time to talk." It is presumed you were talking with "one another" so that can be left out.

Answer (score 1):

No difference. However 'talk together' is more grammatically correct. The reason is you are already together, so 'with' (meaning 'in a group') is unnecessary.

Comment: "talk together" is *not* more grammatically correct.  Both sentences are fully correct.  I would actually say that "talk with each other" is probably slightly more idiomatic, so actually a better choice, but not by a large amount.